# Keep List in the sidebar on same line after collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently used an open-source code for creating Sidebar to implement to my Website.

I'm trying to do 2 things mainly to it. The first thing I wanted to be "collapsed onLoad", I tried doing it myself but the content of it stayed out of the sidebar. The second problem I'm facing is "Keeping the icons on the same line of the content", I want the icons when the sidebar is collapsed to be on the same line of the list when it's open.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide submenus
  $('#body-row .collapse').collapse('hide');

  // Collapse/Expand icon
  $('#collapse-icon').addClass('fa-angle-double-left');

  // Collapse click
  $('[data-toggle=sidebar-colapse]').click(function() {
    SidebarCollapse();
  });

  function SidebarCollapse() {
    $('.menu-collapsed').toggleClass('d-none');
    $('.sidebar-submenu').toggleClass('d-none');
    $('.submenu-icon').toggleClass('d-none');
    $('#sidebar-container').toggleClass('sidebar-expanded sidebar-collapsed');

    // Treating d-flex/d-none on separators with title
    var SeparatorTitle = $('.sidebar-separator-title');
    if (SeparatorTitle.hasClass('d-flex')) {
      SeparatorTitle.removeClass('d-flex');
    } else {
      SeparatorTitle.addClass('d-flex');
    }

    // Collapse/Expand icon
    $('#collapse-icon').toggleClass('fa-angle-double-left fa-angle-double-right');
  }
});
```

```css
#body-row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#sidebar-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Sidebar sizes when expanded and expanded */

.sidebar-expanded {
  width: 230px;
}

.sidebar-collapsed {
  width: 60px;
}


/* Menu item*/

#sidebar-container .list-group a {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}


/* Submenu item*/

#sidebar-container .list-group .sidebar-submenu a {
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.sidebar-submenu {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}


/* Separators */

.sidebar-separator-title {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 35px;
}

.sidebar-separator {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 25px;
}

.logo-separator {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 60px;
}


/* Closed submenu icon */

#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* Opened submenu icon */

#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#push-medown {
  margin-top: 90px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ddcb362732.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Bootstrap row -->
<div class="row" id="body-row">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-container" class="sidebar-expanded d-none d-md-block">
    <!-- d-* hiddens the Sidebar in smaller devices. Its itens can be kept on the Navbar 'Menu' -->
    <!-- Bootstrap List Group -->
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar-colapse" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span id="collapse-icon" class="fas fa-bars mr-3 "></span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- Separator with title -->
      <li class="list-group-item sidebar-separator-title text-muted d-flex align-items-center menu-collapsed" id="push-medown">
        <large>STUDENT</large>
      </li>
      <!-- /END Separator -->
      <!-- Menu with submenu -->

      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fab fa-microsoft fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Dashboard</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-list-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Homework</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Classes</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Grades</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-hourglass-start fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Quizes</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Agenda</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="far fa-calendar-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Calendar</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-volume-up fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Events</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed">Logout</span>
        </div>
      </a>


    </ul>
    <!-- List Group END-->
  </div>
  <!-- sidebar-container END -->

  <!-- MAIN -->
  <div class="col">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        <span class="menu-collapsed">My Bar</span>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>

          <!-- This menu is hidden in bigger devices with d-sm-none. 
                     The sidebar isn't proper for smaller screens imo, so this dropdown menu can keep all the useful sidebar itens exclusively for smaller screens  -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown d-sm-block d-md-none">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="smallerscreenmenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu
                  </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="smallerscreenmenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tasks</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Etc ...</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!-- Smaller devices menu END -->

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NavBar END -->




  </div>
  <!-- Main Col END -->

</div>
<!-- body-row END -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the necessary changes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Hide submenus
  $("#body-row .collapse").collapse("hide");

  // Collapse/Expand icon
  $("#collapse-icon").addClass("fa-angle-double-left");

  // Collapse click
  $("[data-toggle=sidebar-colapse]").click(function() {
    SidebarCollapse();
  });

  function SidebarCollapse() {
    $(".menu-collapsed").toggleClass("d-none");
    $(".sidebar-submenu").toggleClass("d-none");
    $(".submenu-icon").toggleClass("d-none");
    $("#sidebar-container").toggleClass("sidebar-expanded sidebar-collapsed");
    $("#push-medown").toggleClass("open");

    // Collapse/Expand icon
    $("#collapse-icon").toggleClass("fa-angle-double-left fa-angle-double-right");
  }
});
```

```css
#body-row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}

#sidebar-container {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 0;
}


/* Sidebar sizes when expanded and expanded */

.sidebar-expanded {
  width: 230px;
}

.sidebar-collapsed {
  width: 60px;
}


/* Menu item*/

#sidebar-container .list-group a {
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}


/* Submenu item*/

#sidebar-container .list-group .sidebar-submenu a {
  height: 45px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.sidebar-submenu {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}


/* Separators */

.sidebar-separator-title {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 35px;
}

.sidebar-separator {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 25px;
}

.logo-separator {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 60px;
}


/* Closed submenu icon */

#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="false"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0d7";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}


/* Opened submenu icon */

#sidebar-container .list-group .list-group-item[aria-expanded="true"] .submenu-icon::after {
  content: " \f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline;
  text-align: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

#push-medown {
  margin-top: 90px;
  opacity: 0;
}

#push-medown.open {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ddcb362732.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Bootstrap row -->
<div class="row" id="body-row">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-container" class="sidebar-collapsed d-none d-md-block">
    <!-- d-* hiddens the Sidebar in smaller devices. Its itens can be kept on the Navbar 'Menu' -->
    <!-- Bootstrap List Group-->
    <ul class="list-group">
      <a href="#" data-toggle="sidebar-colapse" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class=" w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span id="collapse-icon" class="fas fa-bars mr-3 "></span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <!-- Separator with title -->
      <li class="list-group-item sidebar-separator-title text-muted align-items-center d-flex" id="push-medown">
        <large>STUDENT</large>
      </li>
      <!-- /END Separator -->
      <!-- Menu with submenu -->

      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fab fa-microsoft fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Dashboard</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-list-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Homework</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-chalkboard-teacher fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Classes</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Grades</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-hourglass-start fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Quizes</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Agenda</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="far fa-calendar-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Calendar</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-volume-up fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Events</span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="bg-dark list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-start align-items-center">
          <span class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw mr-3"></span>
          <span class="menu-collapsed d-none">Logout</span>
        </div>
      </a>

    </ul>
    <!-- List Group END-->
  </div>
  <!-- sidebar-container END -->

  <!-- MAIN -->
  <div class="col">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary">
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        <span class="menu-collapsed">My Bar</span>
      </a>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>

          <!-- This menu is hidden in bigger devices with d-sm-none. 
                     The sidebar isn't proper for smaller screens imo, so this dropdown menu can keep all the useful sidebar itens exclusively for smaller screens  -->
          <li class="nav-item dropdown d-sm-block d-md-none">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="smallerscreenmenu" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Menu
                        </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="smallerscreenmenu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Dashboard</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tasks</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Etc ...</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <!-- Smaller devices menu END -->

        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- NavBar END -->

  </div>
  <!-- Main Col END -->

</div>
<!-- body-row END -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

#### [Check it in action on codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/oNBLPjj)